# Reversing wrong CSV encoding

Tags: python, encoding

I'm attempting to fix [a CSV file](https://ufile.io/obhmv8il) that was exported with an incorrect encoding. The first three lines look like this:

```
"\/eÉ\u0099(r)\/","\/É\u009CË\u0090(r)\/","IPA","Notes"
"air","err","Ë\u0088É\u009CË\u0090(r)"
"Baird","bird","Ë\u0088bÉ\u009CË\u0090(r)d"
```

This is the best result I have gotten so far:

```py
>>> print(csv_bytes.decode('utf-8').encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
"\/eə(r)\/","\/ɜː(r)\/","IPA","Notes"
"air","err","ˈɜː(r)"
"Baird","bird","ˈbɜː(r)d"
```

However, it still keep escaping some characters such as `\/` at the beginning. I also tried using [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with no luck.

Comment: How are you obtaining the byte string `csv_bytes`? And what was the incorrect encoding?

Comment: Hi, `csv_bytes` is obtained just by plain reading the file as bytes: `open('doc.csv', 'rb').read()`. I hope I knew what was the incorrect encoding, but I have no clue about how the CSV was generated.